# List of Sub Sites and Workspaces

Tags: 2010, list, content-type, list-view

I would like to create a list of **Project** Sites and links to pages, on the **Projects** site. To contents of *Sites and Workspaces*.

This process should be automatic when you establish a new project site, the list will include a new entry in the list of projects.

I do not know as you pull a list of pages.

example:

1. Home Page

   - Projects

     - Project 1
     - Project 2
     - Project 3
     - Project 4

Comment: I guess my example is not the best show I wanted. This is the structure of pages. I would like to on the main page displays a list of projects. I thought that the list of projects has been kept for example in the list. Then I could see a list of projects on the main page, view our projects page. I do not know how to import a list of pages to list. Do you think in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

If you planned on having your own control hosting it you could rely on the out-of-the-box site map providers already used by various navigation controls like Top navigation, Quick launch bar, which get automatically populated. In the master there is already something like this:

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource
              ShowStartingNode="True"
              SiteMapProvider="SPSiteMapProvider"
              id="topSiteMap"
              runat="server"
              StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002"/>
```

Note that StartingNodeUrl value sid:1002 indicates QuickLaunchBar and sid:1025 is used for TopNavigationBar which give different output nodes. Then you could data-bind these to any Tree-view control or ASP Menu, or actually anything that could data-bind to a IHierarchicalDataSource (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ihierarchicaldatasource(v=vs.90).aspx)